# declare [nameref] as pointer to function, fails

Tags: bash, declare

I want to be able to make a nameref pointer to a function name, using bash declare -n.

Code below demonstrated what i expected should work.

```
#!/bin/bash
  declare -fx _myfunc
  declare -nx myfunc=_myfunc
  _myfunc() {
    echo "123"
    return 0
  }
  echo "myfunc: $(myfunc)"
  echo "_myfunc: $(_myfunc)"
```

expected result:

```
myfunc: 123
_myfunc: 123
```

actual result:

```
myscript: line 9: myfunc: command not found
myfunc: 
_myfunc: 123
```

Comment: Why don't you use an alias for "_myfunc()"?

Comment: it's for use in bash scripts. aliases can only be accessed from the command line.

Comment: How would you use "nameref function pointer"? Why not just `myfunc() { _myfunc "$@"; }` ? functions and variables, like, don't share the namespace, so your nameref `myfunc` doesn't "point" to a function, only to a variable named `_myfunc` (which doesn't exists).

Comment: you have a point @KamilCuk.  is it that namerefs are only for variable names?

Comment: @GaryDean: `shopt -s expand_aliases`

Comment: @Cyrus, Ah yes, the shopt monster. That could also be an alternative should my mission to use declare namref fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accesing the variable myfunc (with ${myfunc}). But you also have to dereference it since it is a pointer to _myfunc.

So, it should be:

```
...
echo "myfunc: $(${!myfunc})"  <--- this changes
echo "_myfunc: $(_myfunc)"
```

and then you will get:

```
myfunc: 123
_myfunc: 123
```